# Running shell commands in .sh file results to error

Tags: shell, shell-script, terminal

I have two following linux shell commands:

```
echo 'CPU type and model'
cat /proc/cpuinfo | head -5 | tail -1
```

When i run these commands directly in Terminal, i get this result truly:

```
CPU type and model
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 CPU       M 330  @ 2.13GHz
```

But when i save them into a `test.sh` file and run `sh test.sh`, i get this error:

```
CPU type and model
tail: option used in invalid context -- 1
```

I also try `bash test.sh` and get this:

```
CPU type and model
tail: option used in invalid context -- 1
```

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but you've got yourself a nice [useless use of cat](http://catb.org/jargon/html/U/UUOC.html) there. Wouldn't it be simpler to simply write `head -n 5 /proc/cpuinfo | tail -n 1`?

Comment: I test it and get `: invalid number of lines
` error.

Comment: Apparently your versions of `head` and `tail` don't support the `-n` options. That was not my point. You could try `head -5 /proc/cpuinfo | tail -1`

Comment: Which is your `bash` version? Mine is `GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release-(x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)` and worked perfectly within both `.sh` file as `./shfile.sh` or `$ sh shfile.sh`, even as `$ ./shell`. Type us yours, as `$ bash -v`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have carriage returns and possibly other extraneous characters in your script file; use `dos2unix` to remove them.

Comment: Thanks, I remove `;` from end of first line, and one of errors fixed, but not all of them.

Comment: I think your current error is because legacy pre-POSIX options don't always work (I wonder about the shell and/or `PATH` you're using that does that, though).  `tail -n1` and `head -n1` are the POSIX versions of `tail -1` and `head -1`.

Comment: I change my script to `tail -n1` and i get `: invalid number of lines` error.

Comment: I wonder if you still have extra characters, then (garbage at the end of the option).  Use `cat -v` to check for control characters in the script.

Comment: Just in the end of all lines there is `^M`.

Comment: That was where this response started... `^M` is not a valid line ending character on Unix-like systems.  Use `dos2unix` to reformat the line endings without the `^M`, or `tr -d '\r'` or some other mechanism to remove them.